# save value from wc -l command to variable

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm trying to get the number of lines that was printed from the ps command, and save to a variable.

```
COUNT_PS= ps -C $NAME | wc -l)
```

the line above prints me `2`, but `COUNT_PS` unfortunately still equals 0 (at the start of the script I've assigned `COUNT_PS` as 0).

It actually prints the value - but doesn't save it to `COUNT_PS`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `var=$(somecommand)` -- as it is, you're setting an empty variable named `COUNT_PS` in the environment while running `ps`.

Comment: That said, the code in question is not good practice. If you have `pgrep`, better to use it, but better than *that* is to use proper lockfiles (as with [`flock`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/flock)) / service management (systemd or launchd or whatever your OS vendor provides) and not to try to grep the process table at all.